# Paged retrieval of a large ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

A database query returns a large ResultSet, and I would like to page the result, something like a cursor where I can choose how many results to retrieve and then in a next loop retrieve the remainders. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try [javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html).

```
 CachedRowSet crs = CachedRowSetImpl();
 crs.setPageSize(100);
 crs.execute(conHandle);

 while(crs.nextPage()) {
  while(crs.next()) {
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display large ResultSet by multiple pages?
I think may be you can use mysql syntax LIMIT.